# Are submarine launched ballistic missiles still inaccurate?

Tags: 20th-century, military, cold-war, nuclear

In the early 1980s documentary [First Strike](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlPEBROvR9w), one of the arguments made for the development of the MX missile program was that in the event of a massive Soviet attack on the land-based missile and bomber forces of the United States, the SLBM force would be "too inaccurate" to effectively target the Soviet strategic missile force.  This inaccuracy would mean that the SLBM force would be restricted to targeting "soft targets" such as cities, air bases, and ports.

What was the cause of the inaccuracy of the SLBM force compared to the land-based ICBM force, and does this difference still exist today?

Comment: +1 Interesting. The agenda of the video seems to be promoting the necessity of second strike counterforce capability. Apparently this was a debate at the time. Based on the dubious idea that a similar counterforce retaliation against the USSR would end the nuclear exchange rather than escalate it. Related [MIT document](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/political-science/17-42-causes-and-prevention-of-war-spring-2009/lecture-notes/MIT17_42S09_lec15.pdf), it also notes Polaris was inaccurate for use against hardened structures.

Comment: Perhaps the real test as to whether you think they are accurate or not would be to ask yourself a simple question. Would you be prepared to discover the truth about their accuracy by being on the receiving end of a test firing?

Comment: test firings have been made, and their accuracy measured. Obviously no life warheads were used but steel or concrete slugs of similar weight and aerodynamic properties.

Comment: @DerekStill Don't be ridiculous. Being unprepared to die testing one's belief is hardly an indication that the belief is unjustified.

Comment: @NathanCooper The idea of 2nd counter strike based on unlocated missile launching platforms (in fact those are submarines) is to neutralize any "try-hard". A "try-hard" would be a tentative from an ennemy to neutralize the nuclear missiles of a country and then become the only one to have nuclear missile

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ballistic missile delivery depends very much on knowing exactly where you are launching from. Early SLBM launch platforms had typical positional uncertainties of 100's of metres. As the missile and any MIRV warheads were just unguided projectiles launch positional errors magnified and the resultant destination error could be very wide.

Land based missiles were preferred as the launch position was known accurately but vulnerable to first force strikes.

Modern SLBM platforms know their position to some centimetres allowing better accuracy and reduced yields for smaller targets. Modern missiles can partially correct for early launch drift, first stage drift by star sight observation reducing the error probability at target by orders of magnitude.

Comment: +1 for a great answer, although I'm tempted to dock you a bit for using metric units in a discussion of USA equipment. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D. The US military uses SI almost exclusively (otherwise working with other nations' military forces would have been a nightmare). "Klick" is slang for kilometer, for example.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos. Imagine the Mars Climate Orbiter incident, but with nuclear weapons.

Comment: I drink beer in pints. I engineer in metric.

Comment: GPS was developed to increase the position correctness of SLBM platforms.

Comment: It is now assumed that GPS will not be available during a nuclear exchange. Certainly UK and French SLBMs do not use it.

Comment: @ExpatEgghead thought real beer drinkers drank in gallons? :)

Comment: @MartinSchröder GPS was designed to be available during limited conflicts, it was only later that people started using it as the sole source of location data, which is foolish in an all out nuclear exchange where the ionisation of the atmosphere will seriously degrade the signal, and the large scale use of Soviet asat weapons to knock out the constellation was expected as well.

Comment: @jwenting and expathead : which is why British forces use satellite GPS but do not rely on it - most vehicles and vessels also use inertial GPS (which does drift over a long time, but is reset at accurate coordinates). Also, British Army surveyors are still trained to map read and use triangulation.